# How to add items to a Dropdownlist that is in SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>() format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a dropdownlist like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.si_sec_id, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Value", "Text"), "Select a Section", new { id = "ddlSection" })
```

it was like that because of this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddlGrade").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("../Employee/PopulateDetails", { id:id},
                   function (marksData) {
                       var select = $("#ddlSection");
                       select.empty();
                       select.append($('<option/>', {
                           value: 0,
                           text: "Select a Section"
                       }));
                       $.each(marksData, function (index, itemData) {
                           select.append($('<option/>', {
                              value: itemData.Value,
                               text: itemData.Text
                           }));
                       });
                   });
        });
    });
```

and the JSON

```
public JsonResult PopulateDetails(string id)
    {

        List<Models.Section> a = new List<Models.Section>();
        Models.ModelActions Ma = new ModelActions();

        a = Ma.getSection(id);

        var marksData = a.Select(c => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = c.sec_name,
            Value = c.sec_id.ToString(),
        });

        return Json(marksData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

now how can i add initial values to the dropdownlist in that format on postback? i need it for my search functionality. comments are much appreciated

EDITED:

VIEW:

```
 <legend>CreateStudent</legend>

            Full Name:
            @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { id = "txtSearch" })
            <input type="submit" value="search" name="submitbutton" />


            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.si_id)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.si_id, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.si_id)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.si_fname)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.si_fname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.si_fname)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.si_mname)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.si_mname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.si_mname)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.si_lname)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.si_lname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.si_lname)
            </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.si_gl_id)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.si_gl_id, new  SelectList(Model.GradeLevel,"gl_id","gl_name"),"Select Grade Level", new { id = "ddlGrade" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.si_gl_id)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.si_sec_id)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.si_sec_id, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Value", "Text"), "Select a Section", new { id = "ddlSection" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.si_sec_id)
         </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create"    name="submitbutton"   />
            </p>
        </fieldset>



            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" name="submitbutton" />
            </p>
```

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegisterStudent(CreateStudent Create, string submitbutton, string searchTerm)
    {

         acgs_qm.Models.ModelActions Ma = new acgs_qm.Models.ModelActions();
        List<CreateStudent> stud = new List<CreateStudent>();

        switch (submitbutton)
        {
            case "search":
                ModelState.Clear();

                var model = new CreateStudent
                {
                    GradeLevel = Ma.getGrade(),
                    //Guardian = Ma.getGuardian(),
                    si_id = Ma.getStringval(searchTerm,"si_id","student_info_tb","si_fullname"),
                    si_fname = Ma.getStringval(searchTerm, "si_fname", "student_info_tb", "si_fullname"),
                    si_mname = Ma.getStringval(searchTerm, "si_mname", "student_info_tb", "si_fullname"),
                    si_lname = Ma.getStringval(searchTerm, "si_lname", "student_info_tb", "si_fullname"),
                    si_gender = Ma.getStringval(searchTerm, "si_gender", "student_info_tb", "si_fullname"),


                };

                return View("RegisterStudent",model);
            case "Create":
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Ma.insertStudent(Create);
                }
                Create.GradeLevel = Ma.getGrade();
                Create.si_id = Ma.getcode("student_info_tb", "si_id", "1");
                return View(Create);
            default:
                return View(Create);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean if your have already populated the second dropdownlist and if your return the view after posting, you want to see the same values as before the submit?

Comment: What do you mean by "initial value to the dropdownlist" ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no there's no value on postback i just want it to have values on post

Comment: @user1672994 i want to add values on the dropdownlist after i post. No value on postback i want it to have new values on post

Comment: Its not clear what your asking. What do you mean _there's no value on postback i just want it to have values on post_?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to add new values on post in that dropdownlistfor :)

Comment: But you are adding values (that's what the script is doing)

Comment: but not on postback :((((( it changes values based on another dropdown without the page loading :(

Comment: Your not explaining the problem. My best interpretation is that (1) you select a value from the first dropdown which then populates the second dropdown (lets say its has values A, B and C) and you select B. (2) You submit the form and `ModelState` is invalid so you return the view. (3) The second dropdown is empty but you want it to display the values A, B and C and have B selected. Is that correct?

Comment: i have a search button that will populate all it's details but in a same form i also have button that will create student that's why i have that script to change values let's set aside the script, i just want to add values on that dropdownlist when i click the search button @StephenMuecke

Comment: What _search button_? What _button that will create student_? And what values do you want to add? You going to have to show some more code and explain what your trying to do. It impossible to give you an answer as it stands.

Comment: @StephenMuecke please see the edited version

Comment: You still have not explained what your wanting to do. When you click the 'Create' button and return the view, what are you wanting to happen?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no don't mind the create, when i click the search button i want to populate details. but the format of the dropdown with this format SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>() making it hard for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your implementation as follows :

```
$.getJSON("../Employee/PopulateDetails", { id:id},
                   function (marksData) {
                       var $select = $("#ddlSection");
                       $select.empty();
                       $select.append('<option value=' + '0' + '>' + 'Select a Section' + '</option>');
                       $.each(marksData, function (index, itemData) {
                           $select.append('<option value=' + itemData.Value + '>' + itemData.Text + '</option>');
                       });
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#ddlSection").change(function () {
    var Id = this.value;           
    if (Id != 0) {
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",                  
          url: "/Employee/PopulateDetails",
          data: JSON.stringify({ Id: Id }),
          dataType: "text",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          processData: false,
          success: function (data) {
                        $("#ddlSection").empty();
                        $('#ddlSection').append("<option value='0'>Select Selection...</option>");
                        var yourArray = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if (yourArray != null) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
                                $('#ddlSection').append("<option value='" + yourArray[i].YourFiledName + "'>" + yourArray[i].YourFiledName + "</option>");
                            }                              
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        if (response != 1) {
                            alert("Error!!!!");
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert("Please Select Any Value Name....");
            }
        });
```